# Take a SINGLE id out from a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to take my id 6 out of my database, but i have tryed serval ways now without any luck. What should i type after`@Model.????` I can't use .Find because i'm taking it out as a IEnumerable, because i use it to printout all tabels another place of the website.

CODE:

```
@model IEnumerable<ForumMvc.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 5px;" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 CategoryBorder CommentHelper">
<div class="CategoryHead">
    <p id="categoryTitle">Predictions <i style="font-size: 15px;">Only for logged in members!</i></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">

</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to show in your View? Why your model is a `IEnumerable` and not a `Category` object? Where is your controller's code? Could you please answer these questions, because it is quite difficult we understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: You are not providing enough context. How is the model generated (`IEnumerable<ForumMvc.Models.Category>`)? Is this view expected to display multiple objects or a single one?

Comment: @if(Model.Category.CategoryId == 6){ Your Code Here }

Comment: It's because i have a foreach also on my page, it is a IEnumreable

Comment: Oh inside your foreach(var item in Model){ if(item.CategoryId == 6) { Your Code } }

Answer (score 1):

The class specified after the @model directive is what you feed the View from your controller code.

If you only want to display one item you can either get the item from the enumerable in your view

```
@{
    var item = Model.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Id == 6)
}
<span>@item.Id</span>
```

Or change your controller to only fetch one item and change the view so that your model is a Category.

For instance, if you have a request url similar to `http://localhost/Home/Item/6` your controller action could look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Item(int id) {
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()) {
        Category model = db.Categories.Find(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and your view could then display this by using this instead.

```
@model ForumMvc.Models.Category
```